# How to run SQL database that can be run on other machines

Tags: java, sql

I am doing a high school Java project where I have to have a SQL database. I am thinking that if I download MySQL on my machine, the marker will not have it on their machine.

Therefore, the program will work at home for me, but the marker may get connection issues.

How do I ensure that my database will be file-based? I also want to include SQL code to write the data to the file.

Comment: What is a "marker"?

Comment: If you want a local, file/based database that you can access from Java using SQL, you can use H2, HyperSQL, or Apache Derby. Those are local java-only databases.

Comment: @TheImpaler, Thank you. I will check those out.

The marker is my teacher who will mark my assignment XD

Comment: Why don't you check with the teacher whether they'll be able to use MySQL on the machine where they'll be doing the marking